# Navigation menu and add button on selective fragments in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need your help to understand the concept of menu in android.
I am using a navigation menu(bar) in android and load it on the MainActivity and put three different fragments.

On app start the navigation menu opened and default fragment also loaded as mentioned below.

[image]

Here everything is ok, but when i click on the third menu option (Credit Cards) then a fragment opened in that fragment, i am using ListView as mentioned below:

[image]

Now i want the add button on the bar, here you can see its below the bar. 
How i can achive this? please help me out. Here i want the burger icon for navigation at left side and add icon/button at right side on same bar.

Note: I tried to add the button on the toolbar i am using inside the DrawerLayout but this button appears on all the fragments.

Here is the code for activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.ac xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragement_container"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.ac>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mas.mas;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.nagivation_drawer_open, R.string.nagivation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container, new TransactionsListFragment()).commit();
            setTitle("Transactions");
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.transactions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.transactions:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container, new TransactionsListFragment()).commit();
                setTitle("Email");
                break;
            case R.id.banks:
//                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container, new MessageFragement()).commit();
                setTitle("Banks");
                break;
            case R.id.cards:
                setTitle("Cards");
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragement_container, new CardsFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Add the button in the toolbar of DrawerLayout and set visibility of button in onNavigationItemSelected.

Comment: Add `menu` to credit card fragment

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi ok but this button event is only work in main activity class and how can i open addBank, addCard fragments on click of same button.

Answer (score 0):

Add button in tool bar in mainActivity

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/adimage"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padd_10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padd_10"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ad"></ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

then use this for onClick Listner In mainActivity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
adsImageView=toolbar.findViewById(R.id.adimage);

adsImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

hope it helps

Comment: i tried this before, main issue is that button listener only work in MainActivity class, and how can i open different add pages on click of same button. Like i want to open AddCard when i will on the cards page and clicked on the add button and AddBanks when i will on the banks button and clicked on the add button.